# How to replace a value of null in ngFor

Tags: angular, ngfor

If the item value is null there is an error in the console and it will stop working.Hence how do I check or replace the value null with my preferences ?

```
this.xx = this.broadCastService.events.subscribe((line: Line) => {
  this.configService.getConfig2()
    .subscribe((e: LineVariantTrack) => {
      this.segments = e.segments;
    });
});
```

And in Template:

```
<tr *ngFor="let x of  segments ">
  <td>
    <label>
      {{x.from.latitude}} //Might be NULL
    </label>
  </td>
  <td>
    <label>
      {{x.to.name}}
    </label>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: use ngIf directive

Comment: is there any other way?

Comment: use filter method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the safe operator(`?`) along with the `||` operator to show some text if the value is `null`

Something along the lines of this:

```
<tr *ngFor="let x of  segments ">
  <td>
    <label>
      {{x?.from?.latitude || 'Not Available'}} //Might be NULL
    </label>
  </td>
  <td>
    <label>
      {{x.to.name}}
    </label>
  </td>
</tr>
```